# Cutting a triangle out of div, BUT have it horizontally centered

Tags: css

Sorry if this has been answered but I can't find it anywhere!!

I need a transparent triangle cut out of a white div (to form a down arrow), I get that it could be css shapes to do it, but the thing I'm stumped on is how to create two 100% width white blocks on either side...

Like this:

[image]

Any help would be great.

Many thanks

Comment: Maybe you could put up an image so we can see the effect you're trying to achieve? Sounds like it might be most **easily** done as a .gif or .png with transparency ...

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I can't! haha, stackoverflow won't let me, I mocked it up on photoshop but I can't post images until I have 10 reputation...is there another way to show you the image?

Comment: You could upload the image to http://imgur.com/ and then link to it from the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Now you've provided an image, I'll change my answer to what you actually want.

The trick I'd use is to create `:before` and `:after` elements that are absolutely positioned, one left and one right.  Each one has borders to create the shapes.  The key to this is the [box-sizing trick](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) which means that the borders are inside the width, rather than added onto, allowing us to define a 50% width for the `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements.

Note that the image I'm using as the background in this demo is rectangular, it doesn't have the triangle in the image!

HMTL

```
<div class="box">
  I'm a box.
</div>
```

CSS

```
/* apply a natural box layout model to all elements */
*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box {
  background: transparent url('http://i.imgur.com/ipGvBz0.png') no-repeat;
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 200px; /* Just to show the image */
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.box:before,
.box:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 50%;
  border-bottom: 20px solid white;  
}

.box:before {
  left: 0;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
}

.box:after {
  right: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/yeril/2/edit)**

Comment: Wow awesomeness and perfect! Thanks so much. All the best.

Comment: No problem, happy to have helped!  It would be nice if the down voter could give a reason?

Comment: I didn't do that did I? I tried to press the up arrow but it said I didn't have enough reputation to do it, I'm seemingly retarded on this site, hope it wasn't me, up all the way!

Comment: Haha no I think it was someone else

Answer (score 1):

**Nota bene:**
The original wording of the question was somewhat ambiguous so this answer isn't exactly spot-on.
Regardless, it's still widely applicable for many similar situations.

---

The general idea can easily be demonstrated with SVG.
The details of the execution are up to your specific situation and you will need to change them accordingly.

[image: Sample image]

[**See a Jsfiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/FaddH/)

SVG images can also be used as background-images if your situation requires that. Alternatively you can hack it by positioning the existing div absolutely and z-indexing it.

See this guide on how to build SVG shapes like the one below: [SVG path element on Jenkov.com](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/path-element.html)
See this article for information on SVG fill principles: [SVG fill on Jenkov.com](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/fill.html)

---

HTML used in the sample:

```
<div id="your_div">
    <svg id="back" viewBox="0 0 100 10" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <path d="M 0,0 L 100,0 100,10 0,10 0,0 M 50,8 L 55,6 52,6 52,2 48,2 48,6 45,6 z" style="fill: white; fill-rule: evenodd;"></path>
    </svg>
</div>
```

CSS used in the example:

```
body {
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/XxGffrU.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center bottom;
    min-height: 1000px;
    margin: 0;
}

#your_div {
    position: fixed;
    top: 30%;
    width: 90%;
    left: 5%;
    height: 100px;
}

#back {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

---

<sup>Disclaimer: I'm not affilated with the linked webpage in any way, they merely have comprehensive guides on the subject.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can use a relatively positioned wrapper and use left:50%; and margin-left:-(half of div width here) in the triangle CSS, as you can see here:

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper{
    position:relative;
    width:50px; /* Same width as .black */
}
.black{
    background:black;
    width:50px;
    height:25px;
}
.triangle {
    position:absolute;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 5px solid transparent; /* Half of triangle width */
    border-right: 5px solid transparent; /* Half of triangle width */
    border-top: 5px solid black; /* Triangle height */
    border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-5px; /* Half of triangle width */
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="triangle"></div>
</div>
```

[**Simple demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TiagoMarinho/97aLA/)

[**Styleful demonstration with text inside div**](http://jsfiddle.net/TiagoMarinho/97aLA/1/)

Comment: Hi guys thanks for your answers, I'm going to try and do a jsfiddle or try and get an image up to explain, in the meantime I will try to explain a bit more, your examples help explain though: you see the triangle you have created? I want that as the 'empty' area, and the areas on either side of the triangle to be white filled in areas, basically it will be the parralax content i am creating that goes behind the triangle...if that makes sense... thanks so much!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jMGm4/       does this help? also, the meadow area is 100% width...